# NSTextField: Converting String to Int aborts (nil) outside of Xcode

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I have a MacOS app that has been working fine for around a year. An NSTextField on a screen containing 20 NSTextFields started aborting with "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". So far, I've done the following:

- Removed and reassigned the textfield's IBOutlet link
- Deleted and rebuilt the textfield

This fixes the app when I run in Xcode in my Development account. When I generate an archive and transfer it to my Production account, it still aborts.

I'm going to assume this is still the culprit, since I don't really get much from the core dump (because I probably don't understand what I'm looking at).

Here's my code. (`game_number` is an `Int`)

```
game_number = Int(gameNumberTextField.stringValue)!
```

When I split the code and do this:

```
let theNumber = (gameNumberTextField.stringValue)!
game_number = Int(theNumber)
```

`theNumber` is a String and correct, but `game_number` is nil

Comment: Don't use exclamation marks carelessly. Unwrap the optional safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTextField` parent class `NSControl` has a property called [integerValue](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/%E2%80%A6) which returns an `Int`:

```
game_number = gameNumberTextField.integerValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You should unwrap the optional value like this:

```
guard let theNumber = gameNumberTextField.integerValue else {
        // Value not found, handle this case
        return
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `intValue` returns an `Int32` not an `Int` and it is not optional

Comment: again it is not optional

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! I knew I could count on the community to make me smarter.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please let us know why you were using the exclamation sign in your code ( trying to unwrap an optional ) ?